# Tracking sales in by landing or entry page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I'm managing an e-commerce website and need to find a way to track sales that come through franchisees without creating a duplicate site for each franchisee.

One way I thought I might be able to do this was to create a unique landing page for each franchisee and then filter sales in Google Analytics to show just the sales that entered through that unique landing page.

I have created a unique landing page and made a purchase after entering through that page but can't find a way in GA to show the information I need.

Any ideas on how to get GA to show this, or any ideas on another way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to track traffic by source is Google Analytics is to use the "campaigns" feature.  This requires that you put "utm" parameters on the landing page for each franchisee.

Here is the page where you can build URLs with the correct parameters: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Then instead of

```
http://example.com/bob-landing.hml
```

You might use

```
http://example.com/?utm_source=bob&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=franchisee
```

As the landing page for your franchisee named "bob".

Then Google Analytics will automatically start tracking all goals back to the bob in an easy to read report.   You'll just have to set up sales to track as a "goal".   Help for that is here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en